# Query FROM "Bigquery Geo Viz" to shareable view - Live map

Tags: google-maps, google-bigquery, google-visualization, looker-studio, google-geolocation

Google has an amazing tool called - [BigQuery Geo Viz](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/)

And I have a simple question, HOW to export a queried map from this tool as a link or anything else, so I can share this map with others??

Someone faced this issue before?? Or I need to create a web page including Google API and so on???

Comment: See my answer below, Meantime, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470123/5221944 for alternative Tool. It does support downloading visualization as an image.

Comment: Stack Overflow community expects programming questions, but as you pointed in your comment - `this question do not need any code or queries ...` - thus down-votes, I think! Check following links for some insight - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask . Hope this explains "why?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, BigQuery Geo Viz does not support sharing visualizations with others, saving a visualization, or downloading a visualization for offline editing

You can see more about BigQuery Geo Viz Tool [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-visualize)

Also, currently, BigQuery GIS visualizations are not supported by Data Studio

*Note word "currently" in above statements - there is a good chance to have all this changed by Next'19 - I would definitely expect so :o)*